# Sql Limit is deprecated?

Tags: sql-server

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers
 WHERE Country='Germany'
 LIMIT 3;
```

This is my sql query and i working with northwind database but sql limit is not working is it deprecated ?

Comment: Based ion Northwind I guess it is MS SQL Server Could you please try SELECT TOP 3* FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE COUNTRY='GERMANY'

Comment: @Sergey this query could be work but i just wondering

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use `LIMIT` - that's MySQL (SQL Server uses `TOP` and/or `OFFSET`). However, `LIMIT` _without_ an `ORDER BY` will give you undefined results. **Always use `ORDER BY` with `LIMIT`!**

Comment: This clause TOP/LIMIT is db-specific,so could you please clarify your RDBMS

Comment: @Sergey Northwind is also MS Access (in 2021? lol...), the current sample database for SQL Server is AdventureWorks.

Comment: i'm using microsoft sql server

Comment: @BerkCinaz What version of SQL Server?

Comment: and i learning from this website [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp]

Comment: last version @Dai

Comment: @BerkCinaz W3Schools.com is a poor resource for learning web-development - most of their content is literally decades old, obsolete, and/or does not encourage modern _safe_ development practices.

Comment: @BerkCinaz What do you mean by "last version"? Tell us the **version number**.

Comment: on that site I do read "Note: Not all database systems support the SELECT TOP clause. MySQL supports the LIMIT clause to select a limited number of records, while Oracle uses FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY and ROWNUM."

Comment: @Dai what could u prefer ?

Comment: @BerkCinaz MIT OpenCourseWare, for SQL it's this one:  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-830-database-systems-fall-2010/

Comment: @Dai sry i just update yesterday, Sql Server Version = 15.0.18384.0

Comment: @Dai Adventureworks is the *old* sample database. Northwind is the ancient, terrible one that shouldn't be used. The current one is WordlWideImporters which targets 2016 and later. Haven't checked it though

Comment: @BerkCinaz W3CSchools is a resource for web development, not database development.

Comment: @Luuk that's wrong too. Which makes W3CSchools really terrible for DB development. SQL Server also supports ROWNUM, and so does MySQL since v8. That's *not* equivalent to TOP/LIMIT though, and won't produce the same execution plans.  The *standard* way is to use `FETCH FIRST ....` but SQL Server only allows this with `ORDER BY`

Comment: @BerkCinaz no database offers more than entry-level support for the SQL standard, so you have to know about the differences in every database. Part of reason is that the SQL standardization process is VERY slow. `FETCH FIRST` was added [in SQL:2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_(SQL)#FETCH_FIRST_clause), although databases supported this one way or another since the 1990s. The Wikipedia page I linked shows just how many different ways are used for the same functionality. When a new feature is standardized it may conflict with existing implementations, leading to even more delays

Comment: @Luuk the accepted answer is 1000% wrong. This will calculate the ROW_NUMBER for *all* columns before filtering. The real answer is the second one. `LIMIT 10,20` is equivalent to `OFFSET 10 FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: if you really think that that answer is soo wrong, why do you not add a comment to it?

Comment: @Luuk because others have already done so and posted the correct answer

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: This is also 1000% wrong: "This will calculate the ROW_NUMBER for all columns before filtering"   (I did a test on MSSQL 2017)

Comment: @Luuk only if you got identical execution plans with `TOP N`, in which case this would be a recent optimization. When I try this with SQL Server 2019 though, I get a query plan that's 10x more expensive *and* gets statistics wrong. `TOP 10` and `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` produce an identical,  cheap execution plan

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the reasons for a full table scan in that example are because of a missing index.